Is it possible to get TypeScript to to understand the following generic object assignment?
Consider the below code:
type Type = 'one' | 'two' | 'three'

type TypeSelection = 'one' | 'two'

interface InnerObject<T extends Type> {
  name: string,
  type: T
}

type Obj<K extends Type> = {
  [P in K]?: InnerObject<P>
} & {
  [P in TypeSelection]: InnerObject<P>
}


const obj: Obj<Type> = {
  one: {
    name: 'a',
    type: 'one'
  },
  two: {
    name: 'a',
    type: 'two'
  }
}

function getInnerObject<T extends Type>(key: T) {
  const selectedObj: InnerObject<T> | undefined = obj[key]
  const defaultObj = obj['one']
}

Playground
We know obj[key] will return InnerObject<T> due to type parameter T being constrained to Types and key being of type T.
Despite that fact, TypeScript throws an error on this assignment: const selectedObj: InnerObject<T> | undefined = obj[key].
The error message:
Type 'InnerObject<"one"> | InnerObject<"two"> | InnerObject<"three"> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'InnerObject<T> | undefined'.
  Type 'InnerObject<"one">' is not assignable to type 'InnerObject<T>'.
    Type '"one"' is not assignable to type 'T'.
      '"one"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Type'.(2322)

It seems it tries to cross-assign all the right hand side possibilities to all the left hand side possibilities.
Is there a way to make it understand that the assignment is fine, without type assertion?

@jcalz Thanks for chiming in. Happy to try, but I am actually not sure why it is not working. If I remove & { [P in TypeSelection]: InnerObject<P> } from Obj, the error goes away, but then I shift the problem onto the defaultObj, as it now does not know that one exists on the object. I am trying to make a similar, but more complex, real life function work, so the OP was my first attempt at an MRE. The question is how to make that function work, but I do not know what the underlying problem / question is.

@jcalz Now done. Hope that made it a bit clearer. Thanks for the guidance.

Great, now we can look at the problem. Unfortunately TS isn't great about higher order generic logic. One would hope that it could recognize how (X & Y)[K] is assignable to X[K] for generic X, but it doesn't. The best you can do is widen to get rid of the intersection before the indexing, as shown in this playground link.  Does that fully address the question as asked? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Great. Yes, that does address the problem. The behavior is surprising to me. Perhaps TS expands (X & Y)[K] into (X)[K] | (Y)[K], which is not assignable to (X)[K]....

It's more like it doesn't try to expand or inspect it much at all. Many generic type operations are effectively deferred. I'll write an answer when I get a chance.

I don't see great documentation about the particular thing you're seeing here (the closest I found is ms/TS#56905), but in general TypeScript doesn't know how to properly perform many type operations on generic types. Often it either defers evaluation (and then refuses to see valid things as assignable to it) or it eagerly reduces the generic type parameter to its constraint (and then erroneously allows unsafe things to happen).
In general it should be true that (X & Y)[K] is assignable to X[K] (assuming K is known to be a key of X). And for specific X, Y, and K types, TypeScript can verify that, but that's only because it just fully evaluates the intersection and the indexed access. But when K is a generic type parameter, TypeScript cannot verify it. It defers the evaluation and leaves it as some effectively opaque thing:
const selectedObject = obj[key];
//    ^? const selectedObject: Obj<Type>[T]

The type Obj<Type> doesn't directly encode the correlation between each key T and the type InnerObject<T>. It's only represented indirectly through the intersection.  And so TypeScript fails to see it:
const selectedObject: InnerObject<T> | undefined = obj[key]; // error!

The error is what you'd get if you tried to assign obj[key] to InnerObject<K> for some generic K unrelated to key. The only way the assignment would be safe is if obj[key] were of type InnerObject<K> for every possible K, which is where it looks like "cross-assignment" stuff is happening.

If you want your assignment to succeed, you need to help TypeScript see the operation as more direct. If you have a mapped type of the form {[P in K]: F<P>} and index into it with the key K, then TypeScript will see it as assignable to F<K>. This is effectively a distributive object type as described in microsoft/TypeScript#47109. You have the required mapped type as part of the Obj<K> definition, so you should be able to widen any Obj<K> to that part safely.
That gives the following approach:
function getInnerObject<T extends Type>(key: T) {
    const o: { [P in Type]?: InnerObject<P> } = obj; // widen
    const selectedObj: InnerObject<T> | undefined = o[key] // index into widened thing
    const defaultObj = obj['one']
}

First we widen obj from Obj<Type> to o of type {[P in Type]?: InnerObject<P>}. That widening is allowed because it's identical to one member of the intersection, and TypeScript does allow widening from X & Y to X.  Then we index into that mapped type with the generic key of type T, so TypeScript sees the resulting value as being assignable to InnerObject<T> | undefined.
Note that you are still holding onto the obj value for later use. The o variable was only there to perform a widening safely. You could done this without another variable using the safe widening x satisfies T as T, where satisfies checks the type and as widens it:
type OT = { [P in Type]?: InnerObject<P> };
const selectedObj: InnerObject<T> | undefined = (obj satisfies OT as OT)[key];

Playground link to code

Thank you, @jcalz. I did some further digging, and it works when InnerObject is a primitive type. The moment it is turned into an object, TS fails. See: https://tsplay.dev/NDjoVW. This must be a bug / error / limitation of TS that should be fixed, right? There is no reason, at least that I can tell, that should cause it to fail just because InnerObject is an object. What do you think? Worth reporting as a bug?

I wouldn't call it a bug, just a possible design limitation. TS evaluates ObjOK more fully even at its declaration (hover over it) so it has a better chance evaluating it enough in generic contexts. You could report it as a suggestion for some use case to support, but my guess is that they wouldn't want to implement any extra work in generic function evaluation unless it was a big win, and this is likely more of an edge case.

Got it, thanks, I will leave it as is with the widening fix.
